# Twitter OAuth Request Token returning Unauthorized

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to get a request token from Twitter OAuth, but I keep getting `401 Unauthorized`, but I have no idea why. I have tried to follow the signature creation as good as I can and was struggling with `400 Bad Request` for a while but finally cracked the code to get a valid request only to be met by the 401.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I just can't find out what.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    string oauth_callback = Uri.EscapeUriString("oob");
    string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
    string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    string oauth_consumer_key = OAUTH_KEY;
    string oauth_version = "1.0";

    // Generate signature
    string baseString = "POST&";
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(client.BaseAddress + "oauth/request_token") + "&";
    // Each oauth value sorted alphabetically
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_callback=" + oauth_callback + "&");
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key + "&");
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&");
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method + "&");
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "&");
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_version=" + oauth_version + "&");

    string signingKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(OAUTH_SECRET) + "&";
    HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));
    string oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseString)));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " +
        "oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce + "\"," +
        "oauth_callback=\"" + oauth_callback + "\"," +
        "oauth_signature_method=\"" + oauth_signature_method + "\"," +
        "oauth_timestamp=\"" + oauth_timestamp + "\"," +
        "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + oauth_consumer_key + "\"," +
        "oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature) + "\"," +
        "oauth_version=\"" + oauth_version + "\""
    );

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("oauth/request_token", "");
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I'm using .Net 4.5 so the `Uri.EscapeDataString()` should give the correct percent encoded string.

**EDIT**

I noticed that the `oauth_nonce` value sometimes included non-alphanumeric characters so I changed the variable calculation to the following:

```
string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
string oauth_nonce = new string(nonce.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

This unfortunately didn't help.

I've also tried `Uri.EscapeUriData()` for all the values in the `Authorization` header, as well as adding a space after each comma (as the documentation on Twitter says so), but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try changing this line to use `DateTime.UtcNow`:

`string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()));`

Comment: Sorry, ignore that, I didn't read what it was being used for properly.

Comment: Putting spaces in URLs is a bad idea to start with: `oauth / request_token`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sorry about that, copy paste error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started from scratch and tried a slightly different approach, but it should've yielded the same result. However, it didn't and instead works as intended!

If anybody can point of the practical difference between this working code and the code in the original question, I would really appreciate it, because to my eyes they produce identical results.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    TimeSpan timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

    Dictionary<string, string> oauth = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["oauth_nonce"] = new string(nonce.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()),
        ["oauth_callback"] = "http://my.callback.url",
        ["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1",
        ["oauth_timestamp"] = Convert.ToInt64(timestamp.TotalSeconds).ToString(),
        ["oauth_consumer_key"] = OAUTH_KEY,
        ["oauth_version"] = "1.0"
    };

    string[] parameterCollectionValues = oauth.Select(parameter =>
            Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Key) + "=" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Value))
        .OrderBy(kv => kv)
        .ToArray();
    string parameterCollection = string.Join("&", parameterCollectionValues);

    string baseString = "POST";
    baseString += "&";
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(client.BaseAddress + "oauth/request_token");
    baseString += "&";
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(parameterCollection);

    string signingKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(OAUTH_SECRET);
    signingKey += "&";
    HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));
    oauth["oauth_signature"] = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseString)));

    string headerString = "OAuth ";
    string[] headerStringValues = oauth.Select(parameter =>
            Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Key) + "=" + "\"" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(parameter.Value) + "\"")
        .ToArray();
    headerString += string.Join(", ", headerStringValues);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", headerString);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("oauth/request_token", "");
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: This totally works. Thanks for publishing it. I was having the damned time with this myself. Each call to the Twitter API seems to be a little different in format and it is maddening. Their examples are not very helpful.

Comment: Your example did indeed work, thank you.  Looking back at the twitter document for [creating the signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html), they neglect to mention that certain requests, like this call to request_token,  require the parameter string to include the oauth_callback="some address" in addition to the other oauth parameters.  Adding in the oauth_callback parameter fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with this so much!

Comment: I specifically logged onto SO, to say you're awesome! Whilst an older question, this solved my issue, especially  after 3 days of scratching my head. OAuth v2 is now out and I managed to get a solid working solution complete in a couple of hours BUT v2 does not have an endpoint to upload media! I rewrote in v1 with so many issues! Thanks for saving my hair line. I was getting super stressed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @GTHvidsten for your example.

By digging into your working second example, I discovered the issue I had with my code, and it's probably the same reason your original example wasn't working.

It's not enough to encode the individual request parameter key/value pairs that constitute the signature base string, but apparently you have to also encode the entire joined key/value request parameter string, which will thus encode the '=' signs. In your second example, this line of code does just that: `baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(parameterCollection);`

In your original example, there is no code that encodes the request parameters.