# Twitter API [1.1] Authentication Request —

Tags: .net, rest, twitter-oauth, restful-authentication, tweetsharp

Need good amount of help on this one. Basically in my application, I am required to access twitter api, fetch the top 50 posts as per a specific search tag and display them. Naturally the agenda of authentication comes in. Now this is giving me severe trouble. My code doesn't work seemingly because of - Bad authentication data [215]. I've used the TweetSharp package to form my code.

I'll post it here --

```
    public class TweetHelper
    public class TweetHelper
    {
        public static string _consumerKey = "whatever";
        public static string _consumerSecret = "whatever";
        public static string _accessToken = "whatever";
        public static string _accessTokenSecret = "whatever";

public static List<TwitterStatus> GetTweetList1()
    {
        TwitterService twitterService = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
        int tweetcount = 1;
```

---->    var tweets_search = twitterService.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#ClimateChange", Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Popular, Count =       50 });
   ---->    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

```
        List<TwitterStatus> resultList = new List<TwitterStatus>(tweets_search.Statuses);
        foreach (var tweet in tweets_search.Statuses)
        {
            try
            {
                tweet.User.ScreenName.ToString();
                tweet.User.Name.ToString();
                tweet.Text.ToString();
                tweet.RetweetCount.ToString();
                tweet.User.FavouritesCount.ToString();
                tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl.ToString();
                tweet.CreatedDate.ToString();
                ("https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=" + tweet.Id).ToString();
                ("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=" + tweet.Id).ToString();
                ("https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=" + tweet.Id).ToString();

                tweetcount++;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }
        }
        return resultList;


    }

}
```

I know 1.0 API version has been deprecated by twitter. And 2.0 hasn't arrived. So it has to be 1.1. As you can see, those two are the problem lines, where the error is happening. What am I doing wrong? Or what piece of information from the API versions is it that I'm wrongly approaching? It can't be that all those keys and tokens, secrets etc are wrong. I copied them correctly all right, while creating my app.One more thing is that, I'm trying this from my dev. environment on my local machine; where I did an edit of the windows host file to make my application run from that specific IP address and behave like a definite url. I also used this, while filling in the details of the website, domain etc. fields during creating the twitter app.

I used rest client postman and all that to cross check the api request thing. And yes, it does return 215 code Bad AUthentication Data. Someone told me, it could happen due to fact that clock on my computer is not time synced with internet. So I did that too just to make sure. Still nothing. I'm in a gloom literally. Kindly help me on this issue. I am finding it tough to get past. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your code hasn't formatted well so it's hard to be sure, but you appear to be calling AuthenticateWith *after* making the Search call. That won't work, if you want to search as a given user you need to call AuthenticateWith first.

However, the Search call you're making *should* still work if your consumer tokens are correct, it's just that you will be searching only public tweets with no followers context. 

Are you sure your consumer key and secret are correct? No extra spaces on the front/end? No changes in case from what was provided by the Twitter API?

Comment: Also are you using a current version of TweetSharp? The original/official Nuget package is no longer supported and has known bugs (albeit not with this symptom AFAIK). TweetSharpAlternative or TweetMoaSharp should both be current.

Comment: Hi @Yort
Thanks so much for replying. Yes, what I intended was to search and show public tweets [based on tag]. Still I will move those two lines and check again. Also I'll double check those keys and secrets I copied. I didn't know of this issue with TweetSharp. Yes, I did add it using the nuget package manager so I presume it added the latest, newest possible stable only. Do you think I should go with those other two instead? Feeling so stuck.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely use one of the other packages. The main one often breaks on long integer ids now used by Twitter.

Comment: Hi @Yort


yeah; interchanged those two lines just as you said. Now the error that it is giving me is -

**JSON integer 2778608971 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'statuses[2].in_reply_to_user_id', line 1, position 14552**


On this line ---->
'var tweets_search = twitterService.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "#RenewableEnergy", Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Popular, Count = 30 });'

Is this the one you were speaking of earlier?

Comment: Yeah, seems to be working okay now. Thanks @Yort. The trouble definitely was cause of the standards that twitter changed in the background from int [int32] to long [int64]. Addressing that specific pinpoint issue resolves all troubles.
Here:
[link] (https://imagebin.ca/v/3UiXS4etAMF3)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. I've posted a revised copy of my comment as an answer for future visitors to this question.

Comment: In case you want to use your own implementation instead of a 3rd party, it's really not hard. This question (that I eventually figured out on my own) is basically all you need to perform authenticated calls to the Twitter API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020273/twitter-oauth-request-token-returning-unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be calling AuthenticateWith *after* making the Search call. That won't work, if you want to search as a given user you need to call AuthenticateWith first.

Also are you using a current version of TweetSharp? The original/official nugget package is no longer supported and has known bugs, especially around long integer handling.

Comment: Hi @Yort

Yes, it is working fine now. Installed TweetMoaSharp. And did some code edits. The data are showing. However I'd like to do a bit more enhancement; I don't know the exact codes/package information to do it. For eg. TwitterStatus.Author is not showing the names of the authors of the tweets. I'd like to show that in my application. Can you tell me, how I should do it.

Comment: Have you tried status.User instead of status.Author? Does that have a name? If you inspect the Raw property of the status which shows the raw json returned by Twitter, does that have the name under either Author or user?

Comment: Hi @Yort

I inspected. In fact Author and User both contain the name of the tweeter. Just don't understand why this behaves anomalously. Also one more thing of peculiarity: any time there's a tweet in some other language than english, suppose Hindi or Japanese or Sri Lankan, the code is throwing an exception - Index out of bounds. This is strange too.    :  O